# Decide if $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ is open or closed.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

The solution states that the ball of radius $\epsilon >0$ around a real number $x$ always contains the non-real number $x+i\epsilon/2$.

I don't understand the answer, for every number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is an open ball, right? For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is an $r>0$ such that I can form an open ball $B_r(x)\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: They're equating $\Bbb R^2$ with $\Bbb C$ and $i$ just means the vector pointing upwards $(0,1)$.  If you take half that vector $(0,\epsilon)$ you get $(0,\epsilon/2)$ which lands in the ball of radius $\epsilon$.

Comment: The point of the solution is that there is **no** value $r$ for which $B_r(x)\subset \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful what the definition of the sets is precisely.

You study a subset of the complex numbers thus your topological objects are those for the complex numbers.

Thus in this context $B_r (x) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \colon |z-x| < r\}$.  So it is the set of all **complex numbers** at a distance less than $r$ from $x$.

Would you be working in a context where the ambient set are the real numbers then $B_r (x) = \{z \in \mathbb{R} \colon |z-x| < r\}$ it is the set of all **real numbers** at a distance less than $r$ from $x$.

Put differently, the notation $B_r (x)$ is slightly imprecise in that it does not make explicit the set relative to which the ball around $x$ is formed, and this information is only implicit. For the context of your exercise you need to complex version.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I have to form the ball in C; if I form the ball then it won't be included in subset R since there are also the imaginary numbers to be added. Then the subset is probably closed since for every $z \in {C-R}$ there is an $r>0$ such that $B_r(z) \subset {C-R}

Comment: Yes, the reals are closed in the complex numbers. The argument you sketch is correct. One can show the complement is open, by noting that for $z$ complex and not real there is an $r>0$ such that $B_r(z)$ does not contain a real number. One can take $r$ as half the absolute value of the imaginary part of $z$ for example.

Answer (score 5):

To decide if $\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$, you must use the topology of $\mathbb{C}$, not of $\mathbb{R}$.  That is, you must take $B_r(x)\subset \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're confusing open balls in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. If you want to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$, you have to prove that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_x(\epsilon) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, where $B_x(\epsilon)$ is a ball in $\mathbb{C}$, meaning that $B_x(\epsilon) = \{ z \mid z \in \mathbb{C}, |z-x| < \epsilon\}$.

Since for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$, $x + i\frac{\epsilon}{2} \in B_x(\epsilon)$ but $x + i\frac{\epsilon}{2} \notin \mathbb{R}$, you can't find any such ball.